# CSS mobile devices and hamburger menu

Tags: css, mobile

I have designed a website that uses a CSS hamburger menu to activate a slidebar with a links to different webpages on the site.

I also have written an iPhone/andriod apps that need to have an hamburger menu that open a slider work that run swift and android code.

I want to add  to the iphone/android hamburger slidebar links to the website (which has it own hamburger menu)

How can I test on the website if it a mobile device or a PC, so I can turn off if "Website" hamburger if its a mobile, since I already have and need the hamburger menu on the mobile.

I have php on the website so I can remove the hamburger menu on the website if its a mobile.

This is the main page

```
<html>


<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-card-2 w3-animate-left" style="display:none" id="mySidebar">
<button class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-large" onclick="w3_close()">Home</button>
<a href="menu_01_angular.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 1</a>
<a href="#"                            class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 2</a>
<a href="#"                            class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Link 3</a>
</div>






<div zclass="w3-main" id="main">
<div class="w3-teal">
<button class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge" onclick="w3_open()">&#9776;</button>
<div class="w3-container">
<h1>My Page</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: it's called responsive and you can achieve that using [css @media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 0):

so there are a few ways of doing this, but a really simple one is something like this:

```
var width = $(window).width(); //jquery
var width = window.innerWidth; //javascript

if(width > 1000){do large screen width display)
else{handle small screen}
```

of course 1000 is just an arbitrary number. it gets tricky because when you consider tables, there really are screens of all sizes so its up to you to determine what belongs where

Comment: If the task at hand requires hiding a HTML element from view, why would you use JS/jQ instead of CSS media-queries?

Comment: that is also another valid solution. that is probably the better solution, this way you would not fill up the dom with hidden elements, but that really isn't an issue. he may also want to be able to have different code that runs on mobile vs desktop, this just gives him another option.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I test on the website if it a mobile device or a PC, so I can
>   turn off if "Website" hamburger if its a mobile,

If I understood you correctly, you could use [CSS @media -rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), to setup CSS rules that only apply to smaller devices. Below is a simple code-snippet example of a CSS media-query.

```
@media (min-width: 700px), handheld
{
    .w3-sidebar
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```